# Java word search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a `List<List<String>>` Where the String is a single character.

```
List {
 List {
  |"r","x","f","b","e","a","r"
 }
 List {
  |"a","r","q","b","o","y","t"
 }
 List {
  |"s","q","z","b","s","b","r"
 }
}
```

So I want to find a word in this (i.e. "bob"), and there is no set size for the length of the list. It is like a word search, so the word can be on the same line, different letters on different lines, etc. How would I do this programmatically? I'm pretty sure that I will have to make a method and call itself in the method, but I am not sure how to this. Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's a syntax error. If it's pseudocode notation, please explain what the `|` mean?

Comment: You mean that this list of lists represents a grid of letters like in those word search problem books you between the tabloids and women's magazines in supermarkets?

Comment: The "etc" leaves out some important detail.  Are we to assume from the outer `List` that the order of the inner `List`s is significant?  Presumably, contiguous letters from the word must appear in either the same or else contiguous sublists; but may the relative orders be reversed?  Likewise, are we to assume that the order of letters in the inner `List`s is also significant?

Comment: @delnan it is pseudocode, the | is just a visual helper it doesn't have a purpose.

@eggyal What you are thinking is absoloutely right, the rules are the same as a regular word search

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (not most efficient) way is to search for the first letter of the word. Then search around that word for the second letter. If you find a match, continue going IN THAT DIRECTION (the logic should be easy for that.) Stop when you finish the word, get a wrong letter, or hit the edge of the board.

The best thing you can do for yourself is to make a method that returns a character (or a String, whatever) for a given X,Y coordinate. It might do something like this:

```
char charAt(int x, int y) {
    return list.get(x).get(y).charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is that you need to test for the edges when you "search around" and "continue going".

Comment: @Ted Hopp - first paragraph, last sentence, last clause "or hit the edge of the board." :-)

Comment: You're right about that. I was thinking about the "search around" part--it seemed to apply only to the "continue going" part.

Comment: @Ted true enough. I could have been more clear on that. In any event, I would hope that's something that anyone who implemented it would quickly find and realize how to overcome that. It's even easier when you have that method, because you can check the length right in there. Information hiding wins again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also search a word with O(n) complexity provided that you build an appropriate internal data structure from your `List<List<String>>`. Here's an example:

```
public class SO5890087 {

    Map<Character, List<Position>> pmaps = 
         new HashMap<Character, List<Position>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] strings = new String[][] {
                { "r", "x", "f", "b", "e", "a", "r" },
                { "a", "r", "q", "b", "o", "y", "t" },
                { "s", "q", "z", "b", "s", "b", "r" } };
        List<List<String>> sss = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
            sss.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings[i])));
        SO5890087 finder = new SO5890087(sss);
        List<Position> positions = finder.findWord("bob");
        for (Position position : positions)
            System.out.println(position);
    }

    public SO5890087(List<List<String>> sss) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sss.size(); i++) {
            List<String> ss = sss.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < ss.size(); j++) {
                Character c = ss.get(j).charAt(0);
                if (! pmaps.containsKey(c))
                    pmaps.put(c, new ArrayList<Position>());
                pmaps.get(c).add(new Position(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Position> findWord(String word) {
        List<Position> result = new ArrayList<Position>();
        char[] cs = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
            if (pmaps.containsKey(cs[i])) {
                result.add(pmaps.get(cs[i]).get(0));
            }
            else {
                result.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    class Position {
        int list;
        int index;

        public Position(int list, int index) {
            this.list = list;
            this.index = index;
        }

        public int getList() {
            return list;
        }

        public int getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Position [list=" + list + ", index=" + index + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Output for `"bob"`:

```
Position [list=0, index=3]
Position [list=1, index=4]
Position [list=0, index=3]
```

Notes:

- a `Position` object identify a `list` and an `index` in that list
- at construction time I build a `Map` where keys are characters, and values are list of `Position` objects, each telling me in which list an and which index in that list I can find that character
- when finding a word, I simply scan the word characters and retrieve the first available `Position` for that character in my `Map`
- you can easily modify the `findWord` method to return all possible combinations
- you can easily add method to update the internal `Map` with additional string in an existing list, or with new lists
- complexity: initialization is O(n^2) (must scan the list of lists of strings); finding a word is O(n)